# Is it possible to open a complete react application in popup?

Tags: reactjs, popup, integration

I have an application consisting of list of devices.On clicking any device item,a popup should open in which react application for that device should open having its own routing configuration.
I googled it ,but did not find any reference of it.
Can any one help me with some ideas?

Answer (score 0):

As official site tells us "React is a js library for building ui". It just shows you some interface and makes it "live" (you can interact with it).

You can render your app in HTML element, which can be a popup content:
`ReactDOM.render(<App />, popupContentNode);`

The main requirement is that node should exist when you'll render your app.